# Transact SQL 2 sum 1 query using case

Tags: sql

HI I`m probably over complicating my code so looking for a better method.

i have an invoice table and I'm comparing 2 date ranges I'm looking for a simple sql statement that will look at the date is in range 1 add to ordertotal1 else  if in date range 2 add to ordertotal2

this is my attempt

```
    SELECT     CUST_CODE,

    CASE
        WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-07-31 23:59:59', 102) THEN  SUM(INV_AMOUNT) AS OrderTotal, SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal
WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-31 23:59:59', 102)  THEN SUM(INV_AMOUNT) AS OrderTotal2, SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal2
    END
    FROM         INVOICES
    WHERE (STATUS = 9)
    GROUP BY CUST_CODE
```

of course this is really wrong and throws up a lot of errors,
i think I'm doomed to running several queries in my php to achieve it, but I`m sure I remember doing something like the above in the past.

FYI: running php 5  Mssql 2000 (not by choice) on apache 2.2 for windows.

Thanks for any help offered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `CASE` statement are missing the `END`:

```
SELECT CUST_CODE,
    CASE
        WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-07-31 23:59:59', 102) 
        THEN  SUM(INV_AMOUNT) END AS OrderTotal, 
        SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal,
    CASE
        WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-31 23:59:59', 102)  
        THEN SUM(INV_AMOUNT) END AS OrderTotal2 
    ---SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal2 not needed
FROM         INVOICES
WHERE (STATUS = 9)
GROUP BY CUST_CODE
```

Or better yet:

```
SELECT CUST_CODE,
    SUM(
        CASE
        WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-07-31 23:59:59', 102) 
        THEN  INV_AMOUNT END) AS OrderTotal, 
        SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal,
    SUM(
        CASE
        WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-31 23:59:59', 102)  
        THEN INV_AMOUNT END ) AS OrderTotal2 
    ---SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal2 not needed
FROM         INVOICES
WHERE (STATUS = 9)
GROUP BY CUST_CODE
```

Comment: `SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal` and `SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal2` are identical. Why have them twice?

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi you are correct, I just removed it. I just replicated the original request not realizing they were the same.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks you are awesome I have being banging my head against keyboard for hours knowing it was possible lol :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the datatype of ORDER_DATE? Why aren't you using CAST:

```
cast('2011-01-01 00:00:00' as DATETIME)
```

Anyways, use this as your two CASE clauses:

```
case
    when ORDER_DATE between cast('2011-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime) and cast('2011-07-31 23:59:59' as datetime)
    then...
end
```

For the rest, you can use bluefeet's query, as it has been simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use two column in your `CASE WHEN ... THEN THEN  SUM(INV_AMOUNT) AS OrderTotal, SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal`

IF I understand your question well, you need a solution which is splitting the INV_AMOUNT into two value OrderTotal and OrderTotal2. If you want to know how much was the value in 2011 and in 2012 separetly, you need something like this:

```
 SELECT CUST_CODE,
        SUM(CASE
            WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
                AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-07-31 23:59:59', 102) 
            THEN  INV_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS OrderTotal, 
            SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal,
        SUM(CASE
            WHEN  ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
                AND ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-07-31 23:59:59', 102)  
            THEN INV_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS OrderTotal2, 
        SUM(PAID_AMT) AS paidTotal2
    FROM         INVOICES
    WHERE (STATUS = 9)
    GROUP BY CUST_CODE
```